# Calendar Event sendNotifications inconsistency when attendee is a secondary calendar

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I am creating and updating events using a service account and there appears to be an inconsistency between how notifications are handled depending on whether the attendee email is a primary or secondary calendar.

In the following example all calendars are set to receive invite and event change notifications by email.

- Joe Smith has a primary calendar j.smith@gmail.com
- Sam Stove has a secondary calendar xxx@group.calendar.google.com
- Event inserted with Joe and Sam as attendee's (sendNotifications => false).

Joe does not receive a notification (as intended), Sam does.  To reiterate Joe and Sam have identical notification settings on their calendars. With sendNotifications => true both receive a notification (as expected).

I am using the PHP API client 2.1 but I tried with 1.x as well and the outcome is the same.  Since sendNotifications is a simple GET parameter I tend to think this is an API issue rather than a client issue.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/reminders#notifications),

> To send email notifications to attendees for events that were inserted or updated via the API, set the `sendNotifications` parameter in the insert/update request to true.

And, do also note that:

> For attendees with non-Google email addresses, these notification emails are the only way they can find out about the event: it won't be added to their calendars automatically.

This additional references might also help:

- [Registering your domain](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#registering-your-domain)
- [Verifying domains for push notifications](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7072069?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it misses the mark a bit.  A secondary calendar is a Google email address and calendar.   Events are added automatically.  There is just no way to suppress notifications.  Also this doesn't really have anything to do with push notifications.